# Howto specify 'Raw Message Delivery' for an SNS subscription using AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops

I've got an *AWS CloudFormation* template that creates an SNS topic and a subscription:

```
"AcceptedTopic":{
            "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
            "Properties": {
                "DisplayName": {"Fn::Join": ["", ["Accepted-", {"Ref": "Env"}]]},
                "TopicName": {"Fn::Join": ["", ["Accepted-", {"Ref": "Env"}]]},
                "Subscription": [{
                    "Endpoint": {"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "SomeQueue" , "Arn" ]},
                    "Protocol": "sqs"
                }]
            }
        }
```

I need to specify the 'Raw Message Delivery' subscription attribute. How can I do that in *AWS CloudFormation*?

Comment: Found someone complaining about the same problem in amazon forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=132373

Answer (score 5):

Now AWS CloudFormation supports it with [AWS::SNS::Subscription](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html). So instead of adding the subscription as a property of the topic, add an Subscription resource linked above.

A caveat though, is that if you already created a topic with that subscription and are now trying to add the attribute, it'd fail miserably with Invalid Parameter error. <s>The cause is it's considering the standalone Subscription added in the template as a new resource and trying to create it. I haven't found a good way around this other than deleting that subscription manually, which is not good practice in production environment.</s>

My solution around this is separating it into 2 steps. First, remove the property subscription from the topic and add a Subscription resource. Then, add new attributes to the subscription resource.

First:

```
{
    "AcceptedTopic": {
        "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
        "Properties": {
            "DisplayName": {
                "Fn::Join": ["", ["Accepted-", {"Ref": "Env"}]]
            },
            "TopicName": {
                "Fn::Join": ["", ["Accepted-", {"Ref": "Env"}]]
            }
        }
    }
    "AcceptedTopicSubscription": {
        "TopicArn": { "Ref": "AcceptedTopic" },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": ["SomeQueue", "Arn"]
        },
        "Protocol": "Sqs"
    }
}
```

Then:

```
{
    ...
    "AcceptedTopicSubscription": {
        "TopicArn": { "Ref": "AcceptedTopic" },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": ["SomeQueue", "Arn"]
        },
        "Protocol": "Sqs",
        "RawMessageDelivery": "true"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing, AWS CloudFormation doesn't support that natively. As an alternate, you can create a Lambda-backed custom resource to get around this limitation and set that attribute using `set-subscription-attributes` instead. Here are some helpful resources to help accomplish that:

- [Lambda-backed custom resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html?shortFooter=true)
- SNS' [set-subscription-attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/set-subscription-attributes.html) API