# Cannot create SQS subscription to an SNS topic through Cloudformation in LocalStack

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, localstack

Using `localstack` I am trying to create a template that does the following:

1. Create an SNS topic
2. Create an SQS queue
3. Create a subscription that subscribes the SQS queue to the SNS topic.

My `docker-compose` file looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:

  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    container_name: localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sns,sqs,cloudformation
      - DEBUG=1
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - HOSTNAME=localstack
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XX
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XX
    ports:
      - "4575:4575"
      - "4576:4576"
      - "4581:4581"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./config/formation.yml:/usr/stuff/formation.yml
      - ./config/init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/init.sh
```

My `init.sh` file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name fincorestack --template-body file:///usr/stuff/formation.yml --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4581
```

And finally my Cloudformation file looks like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'Test'
Resources:
  MySnsTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: MySnsTopic
  MySnsTopicSubscription:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Protocol: sqs
      TopicArn: !Ref MySnsTopic
      Endpoint: !GetAtt
        - MySqsQueue
        - QueueArn
  MySqsQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: MySqsQueue
```

This produces a very vague **500 Internal Server Error**. Since this is `localstack` and I know that the arns are quite static I tried replacing the contents of the `yml` file for the subscriptions `TopcArn` and `Endpoint` with the following:

```
TopicArn: arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:123456789012:MySnsTopic
Endpoint: arn:aws:sqs:elasticmq:000000000000:MySqsQueue
```

This time I am not getting an error but the subscription does not get created. From the debug output of `localstack` I can see this:

[image]

And the subscription is not created. Is this feature not supported in the `Cloudformation` implementation of `localstack` or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been fixed: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1191

Although `TopcArn` and `Endpoint` still need to be hard-coded.

Answer (score 3):

Using docker with localstack in the cli...

start up your localstack

create topic:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x aws --endpoint-url=http://dc-localstack:4566 --region us-east-1 sns create-topic --name jensTopic`
```

response :

```
{
    "SubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:jensTopic:9bf7628e-ee36-49c1-8216-ed5cf5aea1ed"
}
```

create queue:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x aws --endpoint=http://dc-localstack:4566 --region us-east-1 sqs create-queue --queue-name jensQueue
```

get queue arn attribute:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x aws --endpoint-url=http://dc-localstack:4566 --region us-east-1 sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url http://localhost:4566/queue/jensQueue --attribute-names QueueArn
```

response:

```
{
    "Attributes": {
        "QueueArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:jensQueue"
    }
}
```

subscribe queue to topic:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x aws --endpoint-url=http://dc-localstack:4566 --region us-east-1 sns subscribe --topic-arn "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:jensTopic" --protocol sqs --notification-endpoint "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:jensQueue"
```

sanity check:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=x AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=x aws --endpoint-url=http://dc-localstack:4566 --region us-east-1 sns list-subscriptions
```

response:

```
{
    "Subscriptions": [
        {
            "SubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:jensTopic:9bf7628e-ee36-49c1-8216-ed5cf5aea1ed",
            "Owner": "",
            "Protocol": "sqs",
            "Endpoint": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:jensQueue",
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:jensTopic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `QueueArn` isn't an attribute of `AWS::SQS::Queue`, It should just be `Arn`.

Comment: I think you are correct so +1 although I still had issues which are now resolved (see answer).

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround so posting in case anyone else needs this. I have a feeling the creating subscriptions as a resource is simply not supported by `localstack` so instead I create them when defining the SNS Topic resource. Changing the `yml` file to the below did the trick:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'Test'
Resources:
  MySqsQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: MySqsQueue

  MySqsQueue:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: MySqsQueue
      Subscription:
        - Protocol: sqs
          Endpoint:
            "Fn::GetAtt": ["MySqsQueue", "Arn"]
          RawMessageDelivery: 'true'
```

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately creating subscriptions this way does not allow for attributes to be set. In my case I need `RawMessageDelivery=true` which is not supported (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675033/howto-specify-raw-message-delivery-for-an-sns-subscription-using-aws-cloudform)). Quite annoying...